# I am writing a formal proof for the first time

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have written a formal proof for the first time and am looking for input on any errors I may have made or general tips thanks.

**Theorem**: For all real numbers x and y,
                $$x^2 + y^2 + 1 \geq xy+x+y.$$

**Proof**: We prove that the inequality 
                $$x^2 + y^2 + 1 \geq xy+x+y.$$(1)

holds for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ . By algebra, this inequality can be written in the equivalent form:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}2+\frac{x^{2}+1}2+\frac{y^2+1}2 \geq xy + x+y$$

```
            (2)
```

Recall, the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means in its general case is applicable to all nonnegative real numbers and is:

$$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n}}$$

We can apply this to the left hand size of (2) since x and y are squared and any square is nonnegative.

If we do this the AM-GM of the left hand side of (2) is equivalent to:

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}2+\frac{x^{2}+1}2+\frac{y^2+1}2 \geq \sqrt[2]{x^2y^2}+\sqrt[2]{x^2(1)}+\sqrt[2]{y^2(1)}$$
    (3)

When simplified the right-hand side of the inequality (3) is equivalent to the right hand side of (1):
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}2+\frac{x^{2}+1}2+\frac{y^2+1}2 \geq xy + x+y$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: There's a problem with the last step as it is: $\;\sqrt[2]{x^2}=|x|\;$ , and this last equals $\;x\;$ iff $\;x\ge 0\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio is right, but also remember that $\sqrt[2]{x^2}=|x|\geq x\; \forall x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: The phrase "left hand side of (2) is equivalent to" should say "left hand side of (2) equals" etc.

Comment: Use \tag{1} to give equation number $(1)$ etc.